# How to Save Temp Data in MVC

Tags: c#, session, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a three classes

**Person Class**

```
Public class Person
{
    public string PersonID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public List<Project> Projects { get; set; }
    public List<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
}
```

**Project Class**

```
Public class Project
{
    public string ProjectNo { get; set; }
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
}
```

**Contact Class**

```
Public class Contact
{
    public string ContactNo { get; set; }
    public string ContactName { get; set; }
}
```

I am getting **Perosnal Information** , **Project Information** and **Contact Information** from a **webservice** about a Perosn **(PersonID)**

I have  a **Four TABS** on my homepage **Person** , **Project**  ,  **Contact** and **Finish**.
I am able to diplay data in each of these TABS.

Probelm Case:
1)User Edits information in **Perosnal Information page** and clicks save.
2)And then edits  **Project Information page** and clicks save.
3)And then edits **Contact Information** and clicks save.
4)Then goes on **Finish tab** and click **Done with editing**

When User clicks   **Done with editing** in **Finish tab**  then only data should be saved in Database.

My probelm is how to save Temporary Data.
Is there anything like `Session` exists in MVC??

Comment: Yes; MVC does have session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can save your classes to session with something like this.

```
Session["name"] = yourObj;
```

Answer (score 0):

ASP.Net MVC is still an ASP.Net application, so you can use Session. Although I'd recommend making it stateless and saving the user's progress in the database instead.

Answer (score 0):

Before anything, I should state that you shouldn't be storing temporary data in the Session. However:

First we define interface:

```
public interface ISessionWrapper
{
    int SomeInteger { get; set; }
}
```

Then we make HttpContext implementation:

```
public class HttpContextSessionWrapper : ISessionWrapper
{
    private T GetFromSession<T>(string key)
    {
        return (T) HttpContext.Current.Session[key];
    }

    private void SetInSession(string key, object value)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Session[key] = value;
    }

    public int SomeInteger
    {
        get { return GetFromSession<int>("SomeInteger"); }
        set { SetInSession("SomeInteger", value); }
    }
}
```

Then we define our base controller:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    public ISessionWrapper SessionWrapper { get; set; }

    public BaseController()
    {
        SessionWrapper = new HttpContextSessionWrapper();
    }
}
```

Finally:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction(int myNum)
{           
    SessionWrapper.SomeInteger
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On save click of the person info page you can do this:

Session["personInfo"] = personInfoObj;

And to retrieve in the end:

PersonInfoClass personInfoObj= (PersonInfoClass )Session["personInfo"];

(Similarly you can do this for other pages as well)